# Can anyone give me examples for System.equals(....) method

Tags: apex

I am trying to understand why we have equals method in System class and which scenarios we use this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING: based on opinion**

Given that [System.equals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_equals) is equivalent to `==` between two operands I don't think there is anywhere you would really use this since it adds no real clarity; `x == y` is well understood by programmers, so no need for `System.equals(x, y)` in your code (which is unnecessarily verbose too).

I suspect there is some reason it exists related to the way Apex evolved, but that isn't something I can say for sure.

Comment: `equals(x, y)` doesn't even work, you have to use `System.equals(x, y)` instead. That makes it even more useless, as I could reasonably see `if(equals(x, y))` being a thing in some code in some language you wanted to port to Apex, but requiring the namespace as well just makes it a real puzzle. I guess this is literally just a method that someone thought would be useful somehow and it got implemented, then never cleaned up.

Comment: Answer updated to remove `equals(x, y)` which I should have checked :D

Comment: I actually did check; I've never used this method in the ~15 years I've used Apex, and I don't think I was aware it even existed. I technically learned something new today, lol.

Comment: @sfdcfox 
Thank you!